# make buttons stick to side when view rotates

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a view where I in manually in my code add 2 buttons as subview and place them at a specific location (lower right corner).

How do i make them "stick" to the lower right corner when the view is resized? (on rotation)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to set the autoresizingMask of your buttons ?

```
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

It assumes that the `autoresizesSubviews` property of the button's superview is set to `YES` (that is the default value)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

in your `UIViewController` and manually change the frame of the button, changing the origin. i.e:

```
CGRect frame = button.frame;
frame.origin.x += 30;
frame.origin.y -= 20;

button.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Okay, i will try that. I was thinking there was an 'easier' way than actually doing what you suggested. (like in IB where you can define where it sticks to)